# Behaviour of "C:" with ntpath module

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

CPython 3.4.1

```
>>> import ntpath as p
>>> p.isabs('C:')
False
>>> p.isabs('C:\\')
True
>>> p.join('C:', 'foo')
'C:foo'
>>> p.join('C:\\', 'foo')
'C:\\foo'
>>>
```

What I would have expected

```
>>> import ntpath as p
>>> p.isabs('C:')
True
>>> p.join('C:', 'foo')
'C:\\foo'
>>> # others the same
```

1. Why is `C:` not considered absolute, but `C:\` is?
2. Why does `ntpath.join()` not add a slash between `C:` and `foo`?

Comment: If you go back to MS-DOS days, the "C:" path means "the current directory on the disk C:", not "the root of the disk C:". We no longer have per-disk current directories, but I think that still explains why you need to use "C:\" to refer to the root of C:

Comment: @yole, Windows maintains per-disk current directories in 'hidden' environment variables such as `=C:` for the current directory on drive C:. You can't access these values via `os.environ` or the CRT's `getenv` function. You need to use Windows `GetEnvironmentVariable`, or exploit a bug in cmd.exe via `set "` to show all variables, including the 'hidden' ones that start with "=".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is C: not considered absolute

Because without the additional slash it means “the current directory of the C: drive” (each drive having its own current-directory in DOS/Windows):

```
C:\> cd Windows
C:\WINDOWS\> python
Python 2.7.11. (default, ...)
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('C:')
['0.log', 'addins', 'AppPatch', ...
```

(This is the listing of the C:\Windows directory, not the root C:\.)

> Why does ntpath.join() not add a slash between C: and foo?

Maybe you wanted the file `foo` in the C: drive's current directory.

Practical upshot: just because a path is not ‘absolute’ that doesn't mean it's relative to the actual current working directory. Similarly, `\` is an absolute path, but still depends on the current working drive.

(And `riscospath` is even weirder; in general, POSIX is the only platform on which ‘absoluteness’ is a useful concept.)

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer!

Comment: The kernel uses paths that are either absolute in the object namespace or relative to a handle. Drive C: is usually mapped to `\Device\HarddiskVolume[N>=1]`. A path such as `C:` gets resolved using the current directory on drive C:, e.g. to `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows`. The kernel uses the following classifications of MS-DOS paths when translating them to the native namespace: UNC absolute, local device (e.g. `\\.\con`). root local device (e.g. `\\.`), drive absolute (e.g. `C:\Windows`), drive relative (e.g. `C:foo`), rooted (e.g. `\Windows`), and relative (e.g. `foo`).